# Pivot data from wide to long using column suffix to get table with multiple columns with values (using pivot_longer)

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a tibble/dataframe that looks like this:

```
hc_inpatient_sum hc_ambulant_sum hc_inpatient_mean hc_ambulant_mean
5                2               5.5              2.2
```

My desired output is:

```
my_names       sum  mean
hc_inpatient     5   5.5
hc_ambulant      2   2.2
```

I get what I want using the following code. However, it seems pretty complicated. I guess that the same result could be obtained using less complicated code.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

my_data <- tibble(hc_inpatient_sum = 5, hc_ambulant_sum = 2, hc_inpatient_mean = 5.5, 
hc_ambulant_mean = 2.2)

res <- my_data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "my_names", values_to = "my_values") %>% 
  separate(my_names, into = c("my_names", "stats"), sep = "_(?=[^_]+$)") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "stats", values_from = "my_values")
```

Is there a more direct way to get the same result using tidyr::pivot_longer?

Alternatively I could do something like this...

```
res2 <- pivot_longer(my_data, cols = everything(),
             names_to = c(".value", "stats"), 
             names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)") %>% 
  t()

colnames(res2) <- res2["stats",]

res2 <- as_tibble(res2[-1,], rownames = "my_names") %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-my_names), as.double)
```

... but that is even more awkward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in one with...

```
df %>% pivot_longer(everything(), 
                    names_to = c("my_names", ".value"), 
                    names_pattern = "(.+)_(.+$)")

  my_names       sum  mean
  <chr>        <int> <dbl>
1 hc_inpatient     5   5.5
2 hc_ambulant      2   2.2
```

These examples are quite helpful for getting the hang of `pivot_longer` https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. I looked at the examples but was overwhelmed with the names_pattern argument. May you quickly explain what "(.+)_(.+$)" matches?

Comment: @Roccer It is regex. The two captured groups are in (parentheses) - these correspond to `my_names` and the `.value` new column names. The first group captures any string of characters before a `_`, the second is a string after a `_` and including the end-of-line `$`. I agree it can be hard to follow - there are several good guides out there, such as here: https://www.rexegg.com/